# How to make iPhone timer ring only one time?

Tags: iphone, ios, clock

I would like the timer to ring once when it hits 0, but then turn itself off instead of requiring me to press a button on the phone's screen (so that I don't have to clean my hands or lose time while cooking)

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible. When I'm cooking, I use my iPhone/iPad to show the recipes I'm working from, and use kitchen timers. If you do need to use your iPhone, stretch a Saranwrap® or cling-film layer over the screen.